# Problem with choppy audio with VLC when mixing to mono?

Tags: audio-playback, vlc

I'm running the most recentist version of RP OS with most recentist version of VLC on RPI 3 A+.
(Dec 2 2020 Buster) (VLC 3.0.11 Vetinari)

I'm finding that the audio is "chopped" when the "stereo to mono downmixer" is enabled in filters. It sounds like the audio plays for 200-300ms and then silence for 500-600ms back and forth.

I'm curious if:

- Anyone else is experiencing this behavior on RPI.
- Anyone else is experiencing problems with this filter on other platforms (I'm finding that enabling this filter seems to hang VLC on MacOS).
- There is a simple explanation for this.